# Excel VBA Font.Superscript code does not work

Tags: excel, vba

This excel code does not work. Why? Indeed I can not make work any `superscript` code. I use Excel 2007

note: intRow and intColumn are integers which determine the row and column.

```
Cells(intRow, intColumn).Characters(Start:=Len(Cells(intRow, intColumn).Value), Length:=1).Font.Superscript = True
```

Comment: Perhaps qualify the cell with the worksheet? Edit: you should also be able to just use `right()` maybe try that?

Comment: @findwindow It does not work either. I tried.

Comment: Does it throw an error?

Comment: The start value of `Characters` is the length of the cell so the character you are setting to superscript does not exist.  Which characters did you want to set to superscript?

Comment: @Tony Dallimore The last character is the one which I set to superscript. I also tried `Start:=Len(Cells(intRow, intColumn).Value) - 1`.

Comment: I use VB most of the time and I forgot VBA counts characters from 1 so the statement in the question superscripts the last character.  Like Shadow I tried your code on one of my workbooks and it works as you wish. I agree the most likely cause is the statement is being applied to the wrong worksheet.

Comment: Please run the following stattement from your immediate window. It will probably be easiest to replace `intRow` and `intColumn` with the actual row and column numbers. `? Cells(intRow, intColumn).Font.Superscript`.  If the value displayed is "False", no part of the cell has been superscripted. If the value displayed is "Null", part (but not all) of the cell has been superscripted. What font are you using?

Comment: I have just seen your own answer.  I knew you cannot format part of a number but I did not think of that as an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. It is the `format` of the cell. It must be `text`.

Adding that line before the `superscript` line solved the problem:

```
Cells(intRow, intColumn).NumberFormat = "@"
```

Thanks.

Comment: @findwindow `default`: `general` (I think in english it is "general")

Answer (score 0):

You need to fully qualify all your cells. This works:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    SuperscriptLastLetter 1, 1
End Sub

Public Sub SuperscriptLastLetter(ByVal lngRow As Long, ByVal lngCol As Long)

    With ActiveSheet.Cells(lngRow, lngCol)

        .Characters(Start:=Len(.Value), Length:=1).Font.Superscript = True

    End With

End Sub
```

---

[image]