# Conditionally formatting part of string

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to use the following to make the last bit of a cell smaller and superscript (for footnotes). I'm trying to test if the third-to-last character in the cell is an open parenthesis (and therefore the footnote is one digit) and format accordingly, but the following doesn't seem to be working:

```
Sub Footnoter()
'
' Footnote Macro
' Keyboard Shortcut = Ctrl + Shift + Q
'
    If (Len(ActiveCell) - 2) = "(" Then
    With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=Len(ActiveCell) - 2, Length:=3).Font
        .Size = (ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=Len(ActiveCell) - 3, Length:=1).Font.Size - 2)
        .Superscript = True
    End With
    Else
    With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=Len(ActiveCell) - 3, Length:=4).Font
    .Size = (ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=Len(ActiveCell) - 3, Length:=1).Font.Size - 2)
    .Superscript = True
    End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Isn't this saying if the length -2 is ) then run the rest of the code? `Len(ActiveCell) - 2) = "("`

Comment: How is the cell [formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32892403/excel-vba-font-superscript-code-does-not-work/32893111#32893111)?

Comment: I thought Len(ActiveCell) would find the end of the cell, but could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

What you want in this conditional is

```
If Mid(ActiveCell, Len(ActiveCell) - 2, 1) = "(" Then
```